# NTFS: Provide access to just one file in a folder

Tags: ntfs

I've got a windows share.  It's structured like this:

```
| Supervisor1
----> Employee1.xls
----> Employee2.xls
----> Employee3.xls
| Supervisor2
----> Employee4.xls
----> Employee5.xls
```

... and on and on.

I need Supervisor1 and Employee1 to be able to access Employee1.xls.  Supervisor1 and Employee2 need access to Employee2.xls ...etc.

HOWEVER... Employee1 should NOT have access to view Employee2.xls, nor Employee3.xls, nor Employee4.xls ...etc.   Supervisor1 should not have access to Employee4.xls nor Employee5.xls.

... basically, the supervisor and the employee need access to their xls file (think of the xls file as a personal information file).  No one else should have access to them.

I've set "All Users" to be able to "list folder contents" for the parent folder.

I've set each supervisor folder to "Full Control" for the Supervisor.

I've set the individual xls file to "Full Control" for the Employee.

The Employees can open the files, but are unable to save their changes.

Help?

Comment: I think maybe it'd be easier if you have under supervisor1 a folder for each employee and then set that employee to have "modify" access to the folder that matches its name and all beneath files and subfolders explicitly. So supervisor1 can have access to everything from top share or parent folder level and give authenticated users list access to the parent folder and share only (not recursive) and then give the employees the modify access to their own folders. Try something like that for a quick ideas if I didn't make it less clear.

Comment: That would be great.  Unfortunately, my admin people will not allow me to modify the structure of the folder.

Comment: What about setting Supervisors into one Organizational Group on the Server and Employees into a different Group. Employees have access to themselves and Supervisors have access to Employees

Comment: John, not following....

Comment: Server Users and Groups in AD have Groups that can hold members and have access to folders they have control over. So Supervisor 1 had access to all the employee folders.  You may wish to set up specific user folders (not part of USERS) to do this. But it is a way to set up the permissions you want

Comment: They won't allow you to create a folder and some structure to simplify the security but they allow you to manage the security. Okay, so then ask them to set up the security for your needs per the way you need it to work and see what they suggest. If they are technical and have a technical reason why subfolders cannot be created, then ask them how to go about configuring the security. From a sysadmin perspective, not allowing to create folders but allowing to configure NTFS ACL attributes sounds a bit odd. Otherwise, they should maintain the security for you.